# Como definir um timeout para o método recv() em Python?

Tags: python-3.x, socket

Estou criando um programa em *Python* que utiliza `socket`, e me deparei com um bug no programa que ocorre porque o `recv` não informa se a conexão foi encerrada ou não. Alguém aí pode me dizer como definir um `timeout` para o método `recv` utilizando a própria biblioteca `socket` e me dar um exemplo ?

Eu sei que existe o método `settimeout`, porém ele não fez diferença alguma no programa. Eu utilizo windows caso alguém precise saber meu OS.

Parte do meu código:

```
self.__running = True
self.__stop = False
self.__socket.settimeout(10)

if self.__mode == self.CLIENT:

    # Essa variável irá guardar a quantidade de bytes recebidos
    received = 0

    # Cria um arquivo e um bufferWriter para salvar os dados do arquivo baixado
    file = io.FileIO(normpath(self.__path+"/"+self.__filename),'wb')
    bufferedWriter = io.BufferedWriter(file,self.__size)

    # Envia uma confirmação de que está pronto para receber os dados
    self.__socket.send(self.__OK.encode())

    while not self.__stop:

        data = self.__socket.recv(1024)
```

Comment: Experimenta `if not data: break` depois da linha `...recv(1024)`, a ver se é isso que queres

Comment: Ah obrigado, era mais ou menos isso mesmo que eu queria. Eu não sabia que o método recv lançava um erro, obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para solucionar o problema, eu precisava apenas colocar o `recv` dentro de um bloco `try` e caso algum erro fosse lançado, eu apenas utilizaria o `break` para sair do bloco. Dessa forma:

```
while not self.__stop:
    try:
        data = self.__socket.recv(1024)
    except:
        break
```

O problema é que eu não sabia que o `recv` lançava um erro, e além de lançar um erro ele retorna o valor `0`. Por isso o [Miguel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5749/miguel) disse para usar uma verificação `if not data:`. Obrigado [Miguel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5749/miguel)!